# BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly [Spyder]

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, spyder, concurrent.futures

I'm running the following code in Python 3.7 using Spyder 3.3.2.

If i run the code manualy (ie: in Spyder Editor I select the library import en press "F9", then I select the function I want to run and press "F9") it works.

But if I press "Play" in the tool bar to run the complet file it doesn't work, and I get :

```
BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending
```

I'm aware of the problem in Spyder and i'm already running in the current WD. I've also used the trick of the `if __name__ = __main__:` to run my function as main().

The code I'm building is intended to be used by people not familiar with programming, so for them it's much safer to click "Play" than to select and run specific bite of code.

Here's the code, the content of the function doesn't seem to be a problem and paralellize well when working, using 100% of the 8 cores.
If it helps, the biggest file imported is less than 1mb.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from MPO_PROC import N_tab, N_tab_FCT, TYPE, TR
from MPO_FUNC import *

def main():

    """ Set the variables for the loop """
    alpha = 0.05
    alg_type = TYPE
    futures = []
    e = ProcessPoolExecutor(8)

    if alg_type == "O":
        F = FFR_ME
    elif alg_type == "NO":
        F = FFR_ME_NO
    else :
        raise TypeError("Algortithm type selected does not exist. Must be 'O' or 'NO'")

    """ Loop over the different task summarized in the tab 'N_tab' during the MPO_PROC step. """
    for task in N_tab["TASK_NUMBER"]:

         """ Declare variables N, n , f based on the previous calculations """ 

         N = N_tab_FCT.loc[N_tab_FCT["TASK_NUMBER"] == task, "N_Task"]
         n = N_tab_FCT.loc[N_tab_FCT["TASK_NUMBER"] == task, "n_i"]
         f = N_tab_FCT.loc[N_tab_FCT["TASK_NUMBER"] == task, "F"]

         """" Implement the function using the concurrent.future module for multiprocessing. """ 

         for Ni, ni, fi in zip(N,n,f):

             future = e.submit(F, Ni, ni, fi, alpha)                
             futures.append(future)

    results = [ff.result() for ff in futures] 

    for i in range(len(results)):
        f = int(N_tab_FCT.loc[i, "F"])                                                
        N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"LBound"] = results[i][0][f]
        N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"UBound"] = results[i][1][f]
        N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"ME"] = (N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"UBound"] - N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"LBound"])/\
                                               (2*N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"N_Task"])
        N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"FFR"] = (N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"LBound"] + (N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"UBound"] - N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"LBound"])/2)/\
                                                N_tab_FCT.loc[i,"N_Task"]                                                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please update to Spyder 3.3.6 and try again.

Comment: @Carlos, I updated to version 3.3.6 and the problem is still there. Should I update to the lastest version ?

Comment: Sure. If that doesn't fix the problem, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we can keep discussing about this. I find it very strange and I'd like to have it fixed.

Comment: Same problem with the 4.0.1. I'll open an issue, thanks !

Comment: Thanks for your help!